# Load modal with custom data-id

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue with one of my website.

I have some list links like this:

```
<ul>
  <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="10">Room 10</a>
  <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="20">Room 20</a>
</ul>
```

On my `#myModal`, I want the form appears to edit info. So I passed the `data-id`, which is the id into my database.

HTML is the following:

```
<div class="modal modal-open" id="myModal">
  <form class="modal-form form-horizontal">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h3>Room #xx</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body"> <input name="roomNumber" type="text" value="xx">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

My question, is how can I load the rooms infos from my db into the `#myModal` window ?

Step by Step:

1. I click on the Edit room link.
2. The modal loads infos from the db.
3. I can change info.
4. I save the form.
5. The modal close.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Where's the HTML for the modal content?

Comment: Oops, I completely misread the question, sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming an element in your modal with the ID `roomNumber`, such as:

```
<p>Your room number is: <span id="roomNumber"></span>.</p>
```

you'd do something like this to populate it:

```
var myRoomNumber;

$('#rooms li a').click(function() {
   myRoomNumber = $(this).attr('data-id'); 
});

$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $(this).find('.roomNumber').text(myRoomNumber);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/Yafb5

There's probably a way to simplify this by grabbing the click target inside the show function and getting the id there, but it's escaping me at the moment.

---

Update: Found it:

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var myRoomNumber = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-id');
    $(this).find('.roomNumber').text(myRoomNumber);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/Yafb5/4

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem  i.e. getting data-id of clicked element for MODAL.

And This worked for me

```
$('#MyModal').modal().on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {

  var myDataId= $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-id'); 

 });
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( ".button").on("click", function(event){
/* if you want to use the same modal, you must unbind() actions because bootstrap 
   remember olders actions on Modal element */

$( "#MyModal" ).unbind();
var btn = $(this);
var id = $(this).data("id"); /* "data-id" attribute in html */
$.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 url: content_direct_delivery_in_html,
 data: { id: id },
success: function(html) {
 $('#MyModal').modal().on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $("#MyModal_body").html(html);
 });
}
```

Your Html like this :

```
<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm button" data-id="<?php echo $BDD['id']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MyModal">
click me
</button>
```