# How to update specific row using modal Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to update a specific row using `modal`. However I don't have any idea how to pass the value of the row id to the `route` parameter.

**Here's the `update` form.**

```
           <form action="{{route('subcategory.update', 'idhere')}}" method="POST">
                @method('PATCH')
                @csrf
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <label for="editname">New sub-category name:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="editname" id="editname" class="form-control">
                        <input type="text" name="editid" id="editid" value="" hidden>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
            </form>
```

**Edit button**

```
<button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" data-myid="{{$item->id}}" 
        data-mytitle ="{{$item->name}}"
        data-target="#editsub" data-toggle="modal">Edit</button>
```

**And here's the controller**

```
    public function update(Request $request, Subcategory $subcategory)
    {
    // return $request;

    Subcategory::where('id',$request->editid)->update([
        'name' => $request->editname
    ]);

    return back();
    }
```

Comment: You can pass through controller, can i see your form load controller function ?

Comment: I got it working just now. I placed the `modal` inside the `foreach` function. Is that okay in terms of performance???

Comment: You can update your question then others will be able to answer your question easily.

Comment: Duplicating the modal html for every row is fine if you only have a few rows. If you have many, or the number of rows will grow over time, you will soon have a huge html page, slow to load and use. A better option is to have just 1 modal, and use Javascript to update it when a button is clicked. In fact it looks like you were trying this already, you have a `data-myid` on your button.  This is a very common approach and there are many examples here on SO about it - [here's one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22394696/load-modal-with-custom-data-id).

Answer (score 0):

When you pass an `id` here and if your model name is `subcategory.php` you will get the db record in your controller.

```
 <form action="{{route('subcategory.update', $subcategory )}}" method="POST">
```

Or you can do following too

```
<form action="{{route('subcategory.update', $subcategory->id )}}" method="POST">
```

Your route should have `{subcategory}` in it for eager loading. After that you can do following in your code.

```
public function update(Request $request, Subcategory $subcategory)
{

    //variable $subcategory has the db record
    $subcategory->update(['name' => $request->only('editname')]);

    return back();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you can store the `item id` in

```
<input type="text" name="editid" id="editid" value="{$item->id}" hidden>
```

And since you are using `POST` request, you can easily get the `item id` from the request.

Like the one in your post:

```
$request->input('editid');
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try first to pass id in input box hidden field